# Solr alphabetical sorting trouble. Sorting uppercase then lowercase for string type field

Tags: sorting, solr

I've crated a title field with list below:

1. Asking is good
2. But answering is best
3. join the group like this
4. You are the best
5. hey dudes. whass up

When I'm sorting this ASC (&sort=title ASC)

1. Asking is good
2. But answering is best
3. You are the best
4. hey dudes. whass up
5. join the group like this

and (&sort=title DESC)

1. join the group like this
2. hey dudes. whass up
3. You are the best
4. But answering is best
5. Asking is good

But I'm expecting result like: (&sort=title ASC)

1. Asking is good
2. But answering is best
3. hey dudes. whass up
4. join the group like this
5. You are the best

schema.xml

```
<field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="title_sort" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
<copyField source="title" dest="title_sort" />
```

I'm using title_sort field to sort (also tried title field)

Please tell me where I'm going wrong

Comment: I've used "alphaOnlySort" fieldType and its worked.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you use **sort=title_sort ASC**? Isn't it why you created it? text_general includes LowerCaseFilterFactory which removes the distinction.

Comment: Can you explain LowerCaseFilterFactory

Comment: @AlauddinAnsari LowerCaseFilterFactory means even though you sent it upper cased characters, they were all made lowercase during analysis. So now in the index, what's actually indexed is `asking`, `but`, etc.

One trick -- You can do facet.field=title&q=id:<yourdocid> to see the tokens as their indexed in the facets section.

Answer (score 0):

Check this, it might help you.

http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/SOLR-Lucene-sorting-Question-requesting-suggestion-td481965.html